# Is working in a big company with less salary is better than working in a small company with higher pay for a fresher?

Tags: job-change, india

I am currently working in a really big company in India as a software developer. I have less than one year experience, and my salary is manageable. Recently I got an offer from a smaller company and they are offering a good amount, that amount every month can change my way of living even in tier-1 city.

But one of my colleague is saying that, working in a bigger company gets you more and better opportunities in future and at starting the financial growth may be slower but it will accelerate in future. So it's better to work in big and reputed company for at-least 2 years.

I just want to listen to some more suggestions. Which is better, brand value or money?

Comment: Even if it was simply a choice of brand value v money (future earnings/opportunities v present ones) it would be a matter of personal choice. There are so many other variables **specific to the companies concerned** - nature of the work, financial stability, learning opportunities, ability to have large impact, speed of progression, levels of bureaucracy and process - that just "big or small company?" is not a helpful question.

Comment: This can't be answered here because "what is better" is dependent both on the individual company and the asker's personality and value system.

Answer (score 4):

This flirts with the line of VTC due to personal choice - however, I think there is something in here we can answer:

There are different opportunities for Both - sometimes a Bigger company can offer you experience on systems that are out of reach for a small company (high price, cutting-edge tech), however a smaller company tends to have less rigidity around roles, allowing you exposure to systems that might be silo'd off to a separate team in a bigger company.

It's up to you to determine where you place the value. Sometimes having to wear multiple hats can be really good for career advancement, other times it's a distraction from what you want to do.

Comment: What is VTC...?

Comment: @LoremIpsum VTC = Vote to Close - this question really rides the line between 'close for opinion' and 'asking about a specific choice' - it's right on the border, but as I said, I think there's a question in there that can be answered.

Answer (score -1):

> Which is better, brand value or money?

It's clearly a personal decision.

Which is better for you? Figure that out first, then act on it.